# Doing a basic auth req but getting 401

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication, http-authentication

```
    let headers = new Headers()
    credentials = btoa(userName + ":" + password)
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials)
fetch("https://pikaso.me/api/v1/tweet?tweet_id=1468971637223555074", {}, {
    'method':'GET'
    headers:headers
})

    .then(res => res)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Doing this gives a 401 error stating invalid credentials. Using pikaso API refer docs to https://pikaso.me/api

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the headers and method as the second argument to `fetch`. Right now, you're passing an empty object as the second argument, and the headers and method as the third.

Try this instead:

```js
fetch("https://pikaso.me/api/v1/tweet?tweet_id=1468971637223555074", {
    'method':'GET',
    headers:headers
})
```

See the [documentation for the `fetch` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).